# Validate javascript object keys against an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given the following array

```
const validKeyNames = ['name', 'gender', 'hasTheForce']
```

Is it possible to **check an objects key is one of an arrays elements**.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
{ name: 'Luke Skywalker', gender: 'Male', hasTheForce: true } // => true
{ name: 'James Brown', gender: 'Male', hasTheFunk: true } // => false
```

Comment: @synthet1c please explain why? `hasTheFunk` is not one of the `validKeyNames`

Comment: misread the objects keys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `every()` on `Object.Keys()` and check if key exists in array using `includes()`

```js
const validKeyNames = ['name', 'gender', 'hasTheForce']
var a = { name: 'Luke Skywalker', gender: 'Male', hasTheForce: true }
var b = { name: 'James Brown', gender: 'Male', hasTheFunk: true } 

function check(obj, arr) {
  return Object.keys(obj).every(e => arr.includes(e));
}

console.log(check(a, validKeyNames))
console.log(check(b, validKeyNames))
```

Answer (score 1):

I will give you an idea on how to achieve this.

1.Sort the array of valid keys initially using `.sort()`.

2.For each key in the object(using `for in` loop) check whether it is present in the array of valids until `key <= array[iterator]`. Whenever `key > array[iterator]` you can safely confirm that key is not present in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Object.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) and bind the object for checking.

```js
function check(object) {
    return validKeyNames.every({}.hasOwnProperty.bind(object));
}

const validKeyNames = ['name', 'gender', 'hasTheForce']

console.log(check({ name: 'Luke Skywalker', gender: 'Male', hasTheForce: true })); // true
console.log(check({ name: 'James Brown', gender: 'Male', hasTheFunk: true })); // false
```

Comment: Yes but... this fails when you have a target object like `{ name: 'Luke Skywalker', gender: 'Male', hasTheForce: true , batter: 'boo'}`.. Still more valid than the accepted answer...

Comment: @Redu, what fails in the above case?

Comment: OP says "check an objects key is one of an arrays elements" ... so `batter` as an object key (property) is not not one of the array elements.. yet your code returns `true`.check an objects key is one of an arrays elements

Answer (score 0):

I think you can validate using something like this:

```
    const validKeyNames = ['name', 'gender', 'hasTheForce']
var a = { name: 'Luke Skywalker', gender: 'Male', hasTheForce: true }
var b = { name: 'James Brown', gender: 'Male', hasTheFunk: true } 

function check(obj, arr) {
  return Object.keys(obj).sort().toString() === arr.sort().toString()
}

console.log(check(a, validKeyNames))
console.log(check(b, validKeyNames))
```