# How should I validate that keys from object 1 present in object 2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, python-3.x, validation

I have one array which contains all possible input values. Now I want to validate the input against array I have. If all input key is not present in array then it should throw error and if all input keys are present in array then it should print OK. Any nodejs or python runtime is acceptable for me. Please suggest me a better way to do this as I dont want to use something like foreach to iterate over all elements. Thanks in advance.

1 -

```
array = [a,b,c,d];
inputJson = {a:1,z:2}
```

If above is the case then it should print **some error**.

2 -

```
array = [a,b,c,d];
inputJson = {a:1,b:2}
```

In this case it should print **OK**.

Comment: why is it mixed python and javascript here?

Comment: You can Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44240185/validate-javascript-object-keys-against-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `all` in python

**Ex:**

```
array = ["a","b","c","d"]
inputJson = {"a":1,"z":2}

if all(k in array for k in inputJson):
    print("Ok..")
else:
    print("Error!")

# --> Error!
```

---

```
array = ["a","b","c","d"]
inputJson = {"a":1,"b":2}

if all(k in array for k in inputJson):
    print("Ok..")
else:
    print("Error!")

# --> Ok..
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use `set.intersection` over other iterable:

```
>>> l = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> inputJson = {'a':1,'b':2}
>>> set(inputJson.keys()).intersection(l)
{'a', 'b'}
>>> set(l).intersection(inputJson.keys())
{'a', 'b'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution in Node.js. Hope this helps you.

```
function validate(){
  var array = [a,b,c,d];
  var inputJson = {a:1,z:2}

  for(key in inputJson){
    if(array.indexOf(key) === -1){
      return 'ERROR'
    }
  }
  return 'OK'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = ['a','b'];
var inputJson = {a:1,z:2};
const ok = ! Object.keys(inputJson).find(key => !array.includes(key));
```